# How do I show this without using Euler Formula :$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}-i=e^{i\pi}+1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I would like to show  this without using Euler Formula:$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}-i=e^{i\pi}+1$$.?

**Note:** I multiplied both side by $i$ but i don't succeed .

**Edit:** I edited the question because i meant Euler formula and the last very related to the titled question

Thank you for any help

Comment: I think you will need to know $e^{I pi/2}=i $ or some equivalent...

Comment: by this way you have used Euler formula

Comment: Depends on how you define $e^{z}$, then. And $\pi$, for that matter...

Comment: May you meant i can show it bu using series notion

Comment: Since you can prove Euler's identity using series notation, and you can prove this using Euler's identity, you can clearly prove this with series notation...

Comment: Letting $z=e^{i\pi/2}$, you want to show that $z-i=z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i)$. So to prove this, you'd have to prove $z=i$ or $z=1-i$. I don't see how you are going to do this without essentially proving Euler's formula.

Comment: don't forgot that is of the form 0=0

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, and in my humble opinion what i can reply to my student for example if he asked me about that " without using" can I say him no way existed without Euler formula ?

Comment: Without defining what $e^z, z \in \mathbb{C}$ is, none of the $e^{i\pi},e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ make sense. And, inevitably, this leads to Euler's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's Identity refers to $e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0$, whereas Euler's formula refers to $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$. If it is just the identity that needs not to be used, then simply use Euler's formula and plug in the corresponding value for $x$.

On the to hand, if both are not allowed, then a quick derivation of Euler's formula using the sums of trigonometric functions, or the polar representation $e^{ix} = r\left(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)\right)$ should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Without defining what $e^z, z \in \mathbb{C}$ is, none of the $e^{i\pi},e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ make sense. And, inevitably, this leads to Euler's formula. Now, depending on the complexity of the course, either

- easy - define $e^{i\phi}=\cos{\phi}+i\sin{\phi}$, [like this one](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/Free-Lecture-Notes/freecomplexnumbers.pdf), page 7, with some reasoning why this definition works, or
- more dificult - define $e^z$ [using power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Complex_exponential_and_related_functions) and [prove the relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Using_power_series).

Also, using [geometry and vector representations](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx) of complex numbers:

- $e^{i\pi}$ is the exponential (and polar) form of the vector $(-1, 0)$. Now $(-1, 0) + (1, 0) = (0,0)$.
- $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is the exponential (and polar) form of the vector $(0, 1)$ and $i=(0,1)$, so $(0, 1)-(0, 1)=(0,0)$.

One may ask why "inevitably", it's because power series are used to define even more "exotic" exponentials, like $e^A$, wher $A$ is a matrix.